# Why doesn't using the forward as the underlying suffer from pull-to-par and constant volatility in Black's model?

Tags: fixed-income, black

One of the reasons for using Black's model over Black-Scholes to price options on a bond is that the bond price will pull-to-par and hence the constant vol assumption isn't true. Why isn't this also the case for the forward that is used in Black's model? In 'Modern Pricing of Interest-Rate Derivatives' by Rebonato he says:

> 'The naive traders simply did not appreciate the subtle, but fundamental, difference between the Black and the Black and Scholes formulas and the volatilities used as input for both, and believed the pull-to-par phenomenon to be relevant to the Black formula as well.'

So, I guess I'm naive as I can't find an explanation for this, or work it out myself.

This sentence from [the wiki page on bond options](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bond_option#Valuation) doesn't make sense to me:
"Bonds, the underlyers in this case, exhibit what is known as pull-to-par: as the bond reaches its maturity date, all of the prices involved with the bond become known, thereby decreasing its volatility."

Why does the vol decrease here and not with forwards?

Comment: I get that the forward price doesn't drift, but what I don't get is why the volatility of the forward price can be constant. This sentence from [the wiki page on bond options](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bond_option#Valuation):
"Bonds, the underlyers in this case, exhibit what is known as pull-to-par: as the bond reaches its maturity date, all of the prices involved with the bond become known, thereby decreasing its volatility."

Why does the vol decrease here and not with forwards?